# Facedetection in flash

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I got a working code to detect face in flash. It just detects and draws a square mark over the face displayed in flash player. Now I do need when ever a face is detected automatically a photo to be taken. How to implement this? Is there any open source project available for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know anything about Flash, but Google gave me this:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/webcam_motion.html

Comment: Seeking for a one that fulfills my complete needs.